# ASP.NET MVC Nuget Enabling-Migrations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I am learning about ASP.NET MVC5 with Entity Framework. For my learning I'm using Lynda Video tutorials and I am stuck at the Nuget Console where I have to run the following code:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextType ApplicationDbContext
```

After i run it I got the folowin error:

> Enable-Migrations -ContextType ApplicationDbContext Exception calling
>   "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:...\Projects\Lynda MVC - Exercise Files\Ch3 - 
>   continue\Start\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At C:...\Projects\Lynda MVC - Exercise Files\Ch3 -
>   continue\Start\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:5
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsP ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:...\Projects\Lynda
>   MVC - Exercise Files\Ch3 -
>   continue\Start\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file:///C:...\Projects\Lynda MVC - Exercise Files\Ch3 
>   - continue\Start\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" At C:...\Projects\Lynda MVC - Exercise Files\Ch3 -
>   continue\Start\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809
>   char:5
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException

If you can help me with any solution it will be a big help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception raised when I'm trying enable migrations in EF 4.3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999561/exception-raised-when-im-trying-enable-migrations-in-ef-4-3-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '-ContextTypeName`switch instead, and specify your`DBContext` class. i.e,

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Someproject.DepartmentDb
```

For more useful switches, refer [THIS](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/)

Comment: Thx for the link I will try some combinations and if i am stuck I will reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My project was stored in a network drive. There are many security policies applied to my PC. I moved my project to the local hard drive, and the problem was solved.

It seems like "EntityFramework.Powershell.utility.dll" is tring to use some powershell functionality, and the system is preventing to execute such calls, maybe because the dll that is calling powershell is not a local file.

In your case, make sure that you do not have any security policy or system configuration that would prevent your system to call to the problematical extension (EntityFramework.Powershell.utility.dll).