# Exception when trying to migrate database in Entity Framework v6.2.0 in Visual Studio v15.8.4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have setup a database using Entity Framework, code first, every time I try to add a migration or update the database I get the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBmp4.png):

```
PM> update-database
Exception calling "CreateInstance" with "7" argument(s): "Constructor on type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DomainDispatcher' not found."
At D:\WTS Projects\ModelCalibration\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:783 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMethodException

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.WriteLine(String message)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have copied the project to another computer with the same version of Visual Studio, Entity Framework & Windows and I am able to migrate the database with no issues at all. I have also downloaded the sample project on these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) on both machines, and got the same exception on this machine but the other one again had no issues, so I believe its nothing to do with my code.

The only solution I have been able to find is on this thread [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/594), where the solution was to reinstall windows which I am not so keen to do.

I have also tried everything said in other similar SO posts, such as [Exception raised when I'm trying enable migrations in EF 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999561/exception-raised-when-im-trying-enable-migrations-in-ef-4-3-1)
, which was to, reinstall Entity Framework, repair Visual Studio, etc...

I am using Enitiy Framework v6.2.0, Visual Studio v15.8.4, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Windows 10.

Has anyone seen this issue before and/or know any possible solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/594)?

Comment: @stuartd Yeah, that's the one linked in my post

Comment: What version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: @Zysce sorry I forgot to include, I am using 4.6.1.

Comment: If you enable the fusion log https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2013/01/02/activer-le-fusion-log-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/ then try to add migration, do you have any error in the fusion log? Btw, is your computer x86 or x64?

Comment: Do you get this error when creating a blank new project and enabling migrations? Just to try to see if it's project based or more systemic...

Comment: @Zysce I will give that a go now and let you know, and it is a x64 computer

Comment: @Wurd I'm pretty sure its systemic, I've downloaded the same sample project from the microsoft docs and tried to enable migrations of two different machines, no problems for one but I get the same error on my machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found a solution that works, thanks to @rho24 on this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/594)! I will also repost the solution here for anyone that has the issue:

The problem is that on my machine is that version 3.0.0.0 of the System.Management.Automation assembly is loaded in the package management console, and EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll is build against version 1.0.0.0.

I have a temporary fix of adding the following binding redirect to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_313c23f6\devenv.exe.config`

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Management.Automation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
    <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Note, the fix needs to be applied everytime you update VS.

I was able to figure this out as its the same issue as this one `PowerShell/PowerShell#6189`.

Which i was also having, but was fixed in a recent VS update. Hopefully the fix they applied is easy for you too!

Again credit to @rho24 for the solution! :D

Comment: This also resolved the same issue in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, but the file edited was in the folder C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_4545fd97

Comment: A shortcut to the first part of the path is %LOCALAPPDATA% btw

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes work to just clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: Tried cleaning it and sadly no luck

Comment: This was the option I mostly succesfully used as student. The other option was recreating the project, but there is probably an easier question. I'm not that used to visual studio anymore